# On click UIImageView SWIFT not working

Tags: ios, swift, image, google-maps, uigesturerecognizer

There is an object called "imageView", I need to call the function "clicouCrosshair" always when the "imageView" is clicked, but it's not working. I've tryed some different tutorials that I found on internet but no success. Anyone know why and how can I solve this?

I think the problem is because i'm using my view as a GMSMapView.. 
Inside the "prepareMap" function the "UIImageView" is configured.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class Maps_criarArea: UIViewController {

    var projNome:String!;
    var mapView:GMSMapView!;

    var imageView:UIImageView!;

    func clicouCrosshair(sender: AnyObject){
        print("CROSSHAIR");
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();


        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyB62KDZSGfbbN1IIVnlhewi4PpEZmxPJYM");


        let centerBR_lat = -15.30;
        let centerBR_lng = -49.57;

        let cameraP = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(centerBR_lat, longitude: centerBR_lng, zoom: 4);
        mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame( CGRectZero, camera: cameraP)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        view = mapView;

        self.prepareMap();
    }

    func prepareMap(){

        let imageName = "crosshair";
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName);
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image!);

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;
        let WidthPosition = (screenSize.width*0.5)-32;
        let heightPosition = (screenSize.height*0.5)-32;

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: WidthPosition, y: heightPosition, width: 64, height: 64);
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true;


        let detectTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.clicouCrosshair(_:))  )
        //detectTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1


        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(detectTap)

        mapView.addSubview(imageView);







    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



    //returning to view
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let saveBtn : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Salvar", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(Maps_criarArea.salvar(_:)) )
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveBtn
    }

    func salvar(sender:UIBarButtonItem){

    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, if you override viewWillAppear then call it super.viewWillAppear(animated)

Comment: All right, did it. But the problem still there :(

Comment: Your selector does not look right. Try #selector(Maps_criarArea.clicouCrosshair(_:)) instead

Comment: Still no success :/ is that possible that the click of the mouse on the simulator is not equals a touch?

Comment: Lot's of people get burned by this.  UIImageView interaction is not enabled by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735247/uitapgesturerecognizer-on-uiimageview-within-uitablevlewcell-not-getting-called/7735403#7735403

Comment: `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true;` I use this in my code.. I think this is not the problem :/ or the ordem that I used this may be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by mshresth the problem was with the recognization of the gestures like touch.

In order to solve this I change my approach to the problem, instead of trying to add a image with a GestureRecognizer inside a UIView that holds the map, i added the UIView inside the main UIView (view).

Add the map as sub view to view:

```
    // PREPARA O MAPA
    let centerBR_lat = -15.30;
    let centerBR_lng = -49.57;
    let cameraP = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(centerBR_lat, longitude: centerBR_lng, zoom: 4);
    mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame( CGRectZero, camera: cameraP)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;
    mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height);
    view.addSubview(mapView);
```

and to add the image with the gestureRecognizer:

```
    let imageName = "crosshair";
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName);
    let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image!);
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: (screenSize.width*0.5)-32, y: (screenSize.height*0.5)-32, width: 64, height: 64);
    let detectTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Maps_criarArea.clicouCrosshair(_:))  )
    //detectTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(detectTap)
    view.addSubview(imageView);
```

the fuction that contains both of the code above just have them inside it.

This way I was able to add the map, add the image and call a function when the image was pressed

Thanks to everybody who helped

Complete code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class Maps_criarArea: UIViewController {

    var projNome:String!;
    var mapView:GMSMapView!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad();


        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyB62KDZSGfbbN1IIVnlhewi4PpEZmxPJYM");

        self.prepareMap();
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func prepareMap(){



        // PREPARA O MAPA
        let centerBR_lat = -15.30;
        let centerBR_lng = -49.57;
        let cameraP = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(centerBR_lat, longitude: centerBR_lng, zoom: 4);
        mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame( CGRectZero, camera: cameraP)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;
        mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height);
        view.addSubview(mapView);



        let imageName = "crosshair";
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName);
        let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(image: image!);
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: (screenSize.width*0.5)-32, y: (screenSize.height*0.5)-32, width: 64, height: 64);
        let detectTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Maps_criarArea.clicouCrosshair(_:))  )
        //detectTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(detectTap)
        view.addSubview(imageView);

    }

    func clicouCrosshair(sender: AnyObject){
        print("CROSSHAIR");
    }





    //returning to view
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        let saveBtn : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Salvar", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(Maps_criarArea.salvar(_:)) )
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveBtn
    }

    func salvar(sender:UIBarButtonItem){
        print("salvar");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your UIImageView is inside your GMSMapView and you tap is always being handled by GMSMapView. Try to ignore the tap in GMSMapView and pass it to the UIImageView. Add [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/) in you view and use the delegate method `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`. Hope this helps.

Comment: In fact the problem was with the gesture recognizer! I found a way to solve this. I'll post bellow

Comment: why not accept this answer if you think it was helpful

Comment: Ya I did see it. Great job.